# Check Existence of Column in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have asked to create a function that can update a MongoDb collection by passing it's column names and corresponding values.The function that I wrote(in test phase now) will accept column names, values, collection name etc.before updating I want to check whether the given collection exists and column names provided exists in a that collection and if everything is fine go and update the collection.I was able to check if a collection exists or not but failed in doing the same for Columns.
I found this in Mongodb website 
`{ item : { $exists: false } }`
 but i didn't found the exact c# code for doing the same. Is it possible with c# to check if a column exists in MongoDb ? MongoDb version 4.0 is what i am using now.

Note : I don't have any strongly typed data, Since the function is unaware of the collection and the type of data it holds. The goal is to accept column names and values and update to those fields that have passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find documents where a property doesn't exist, you can use the following code:

```
var modelsWithoutItem = collection.Find(
    Builders<DocModel>.Filter.Exists(m => m.Item, false)
);
```

or if you don't have strongly typed data:

```
var modelsWithoutItem = collection.Find(
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("item", false)
);
```

Comment: I dont have any strongly typed data with me, the goal of that function is to update any mongodb collection by passing its column names and corresponding values. So that DocModel that you have mentioned won't work I guess???

Comment: @Joker you should mention these things in the question. Anyway, I've updated with an example.

Comment: Sorry at first I had those. accidently removed it. updated the question

Comment: No it isn't. its throwing an error... Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluent<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' to 'bool'

Comment: Have you included all the necessary usings?: `using MongoDB.Driver; using MongoDB.Bson;`? Is your collection `IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection;`?

Comment: Yes. I have included `using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;` and yes my collection is `IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection`

Comment: You must be doing something wrong beyond the sample I've given above to be getting that compile error. Please copy the sample [here](https://pastebin.com/sjdUgtQX) into a new file. If there's still a problem, please can you show me enough code to reproduce that compile error?

Comment: [Works here](https://imgur.com/a/LEZfWnz) with the latest MongoDB driver (v2.7.0, from NuGet)

Answer (score 0):

```
       var fieldExists = _collection.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("item",true));
       if (fieldExists.CountDocuments() > 0){
               // yes document with this field is available
       }else{
               // No documents with that field name exists
       }
```

@john Thank you for the quick response, with a bit of update i have got what I wanted.